# Is Jordan outer measure finitely additive on positively separated sets in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is Jordan outer measure finitely additive on positively separated sets in $\mathbb{R}$? If not, can someone please give a counter example?